# java.nio.file.Path vs sun.nio.fs.UnixPath

Tags: java, nio

Almost all file I/O operations in my Java code uses `java.nio.*`. While debugging a piece of code today, however, I noticed that the debugger (Intellij IDEA 14) was showing the following piece of information for a `java.nio.file.Path` instance:

[image: debugger-screenshot]

Why is `java.nio.file.Path` object being shown as `sun.nio.fs.UnixPath` object in the debugger? What is the difference between these two classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`java.nio.file.Path` is an interface, `sun.nio.fs.UnixPath` is its concrete implementation in your environment. If for example you run your code on Windows you see `sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath`.